# Java class path plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classloader

I'm currently working on an Eclipse editor plug-in that supports completion proposals for the user. To support that I need to know which classes the DSL has, so I can provide them as proposals. Note, the proposals come from another project than the actual plug-in, provided by a classLoader. At the "DSL-side" I use:

```
 System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

and then load the classes from the .jar files provided.

It works fine when I'm testing it but when it's invoked from the plug-in, only one .jar file is found, namely:

\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: do you want to load all jars as proposals? Or just a  special "proposal.jar"? How do you load the classes from the jar? (classloader or a third party library?) Is the proposal jar which you want to load in the plugin runtime path?

Comment: I want to load all jars and then i load all classes with a classloader. the only loaded jar right now is located in /eclipse/plugins, which is niether my plug-in directory or the DLS-directory..

Comment: Yup, that's because the current Java process is Eclipse's process, that has a specific classpath set (IIRC you can see it in `eclipse.ini`). Other CP entries should defined in the MANIFEST of that Jar. What you need is to find the current project's build path and construct the classpath based on these settings.

Comment: Okay sounds good. How do I customize that jar? I can find it in my directories but i can't find the associated manifest file.